# How do I iterate over every row and insert rows at the same time with openpyxl in Python?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am trying to use Openpyxl and iter_row() to iterate through every row of an excel spreadsheet and take the strings in each cell, split them by commas into values, add rows for each comma it found, then insert the values that were split out into their own rows/cells.

Sample before script has run data:

(152, 126), (14, 13)

(159, 144), (24, 43)

Cell A1 for example contains a string of 152, 126, cell B2 has the 14... Cell A2 has the 159... etc.

After script has run data:

(152), (14)

(126), (13)

(159), (24)

(144), (43)

Note: I am just doing an initial pass on  the first column of data to add rows, then after that I’m going to go and split the data out for each cell into the appropriate rows/columns. I am failing at adding the rows so far, I can’t get it to continue adding them from rows after the first set... Any ideas? Thanks!

My initial failing code that is trying to insert the rows:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
workbook = load_workbook(filename="test.xlsx")

sheet = workbook.active

def insert_comma_rows():
    for idx, row in enumerate(sheet.iter_rows()):
        for cell in row:
            if cell.column == 1:
                curr_val = str(cell.value)
                comma_count = curr_val.count(",")
                if(comma_count > 0):
                    sheet.insert_rows(idx=(idx+2), amount=comma_count)

insert_comma_rows()

for row in sheet.iter_rows(values_only=True):
    print(row)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the first loop `sheet.insert_rows(idx=(idx+2), amount=comma_count)` will add a blank row,  with the index `(idx+2)` as 2 and the amount of rows `curr_val.count(",")` as 1.

It looks like instead of adding blank rows you want to add data. Consider using  `sheet.append()` with passes in an array of values for each column e.g `sheet.append(['col1', 'col2', col3')])`

**As an example:**

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
workbook = load_workbook(filename="test.xlsx")
    
sheet = workbook.active
    
def insert_comma_rows():
    for idx, row in enumerate(sheet.iter_rows()):
        col1 = row[0].value.split(",")
        col2 = row[1].value.split(",")

        sheet.append([col1[0].strip(), col2[0].strip()]) # strip removes whitespaces.
        sheet.append([col1[1].strip(), col2[1].strip()])
        
insert_comma_rows()

for row in sheet.iter_rows(values_only=True):
    print(row)
```

**Output:**

```
('152, 126', '14, 13')
('159, 144', '24, 43')
('152', '14')
('126', '13')
('159', '24')
('144', '43')
```

*It's not really relevant for the question, but I would suggest separating code into methods to fetch the data, transform it and then save it to a different file*.

Comment: Awesome, thanks Greg. I also found out that inserting rows is not possible with iter_rows(), so your solution is very helpful.

Comment: It's worth noting that this approach avoids a common gotcha in Python: changing the contents of a sequence while looping over it. Best practice would be to collect the data for the new rows and an index as you loop over them and then loop over this in a second step.